# There is anything to consider in change IIS Pool Identity to Network Service instead ApplicationPoolIdentity?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, iis-7.5, identity-management

I'm facing a problem with IIS Pool Identity. I need to give right permissions to it user, but i cannot find the user that is setted to the IIS Pool Identity, that is ApplicationPoolIdentity. I find the user NetworkService that is a possible user to IIS Pool Identity. There is any problem or anything that i have to consider after change the IIS Pool Identity to NetworkService?

OBS: I'm using Windows 7 (IIS 7.5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't if you can avoid it - using NetworkService means your app pool runs as an identity equivalent with many other services on the box.

ApplicationPoolIdentity is a virtual user account which maps to the Application Pool name. They're not visible in Local Users and Groups (except where you've made it a member of a group).

You can assign permissions in an Object Picker or other username-accepting place by specifying

`IIS AppPool\AppPoolNameHere`

(Note the spacing).

It's not something you can browse to directly, but it is an item with a SID, so can be used to secure any securable resource (files, folders, registry, etc).

Any IIS worker process is also a member of IIS_IUSRS by default, but if you want to be more precise and secure stuff so only one app pool can use it, use AppPoolIdentity to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what else your application is doing - but generally speaking, it should work with no issue.

If you need to assign rights in a very granular way to the application, I'd suggest creating a new user specifically for the app pool identity instead of using Network Service.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use network service if you don't need network resources.  Are you accessing a UNC path, if you are, I'd use a domain account vs. network service.  Use ApplicationPoolIdentity is the most secure method.